# How do I pass an array to function by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

I want to pass array to function by reference. This function will  dynamically allocate the elements.

This code give me an error message: `access violation`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void func(int* ptr)
{
    ptr = new int[2]; 
    ptr[0] = 1; 
    ptr[1] = 2; 
}

void main()
{ 
    int* arr = 0;
    func(arr);
    cout << arr[0] << endl; // error here 
}
```

Comment: `int * ptr` ain't reference.

Comment: A) you don't have an array. B) You aren't passing an array by reference. If you did, the compiler would tell you about A).

Comment: @logicStuff , yes  I should add  & 

@ juanchopanza  , how the compiler tells me ?

Answer (score 3):

C++ passes arguments by value. If you want to pass an `int` pointer by reference, you need to tell C++ the type is "reference to pointer to `int`": `int*&`.

Thus, your function prototype should be

```
void func(int*& ptr);
```

Note that you are still not handling pointers or references to arrays, but rather a pointer to the first element, which is close but not the same.

If you really wanted to pass an array of size `2` by reference, your function prototype would look like this:

```
void func(int(&my_array)[2]);
```

Comment: Function has  number of elements  so i want  function to allocate  array for main 

void func(int(&my_array)[2]);     <----- I do not know number of elements

Comment: @DaliaShouman Then you cannot pass an array, and must instead pass a pointer to the first element (and possibly an additional size argument).

Answer (score 0):

First of all function main shall have return type `int`.

As for your question then either you have to pass the pointer by reference or pass pointer to pointer.  Or you could simply return pointer from the function.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows the three approaches. Take into account that you could use smart pointer `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <iostream>

int * func()
{
    int *ptr = new int[2]; 

    ptr[0] = 1; 
    ptr[1] = 2; 

    return ptr;
}

void func( int **ptr )
{
    delete [] *ptr;

    *ptr = new int[2]; 

    ( *ptr )[0] = 3; 
    ( *ptr )[1] = 4; 
}

void func( int * &ptr )
{
    delete [] ptr;

    ptr = new int[2]; 

    ptr[0] = 5; 
    ptr[1] = 6; 
}

int main()
{ 
    int *arr = func();

    std::cout << arr[0] << ", " << arr[1] << std::endl;

    func( &arr );

    std::cout << arr[0] << ", " << arr[1] << std::endl;

    func( arr );

    std::cout << arr[0] << ", " << arr[1] << std::endl;

   delete [] arr;
}
```

And one more example of using `std::unique_ptr`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::unique_ptr<int[]> func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p( new int[2] );

    p[0] = 1; 
    p[1] = 2; 

    return p;
}

void func( std::unique_ptr<int[]> &p )
{
    p.reset( new int[2] );

    p[0] = 3; 
    p[1] = 4; 
}


int main()
{ 
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p = func();

    std::cout << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << std::endl;

    func( p );

    std::cout << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << std::endl;
 }
```

As you see in this case you need not bother about calling operator `delete []`